# I want an event to trigger with the enter/return button and my UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a `UITextField` and a button next to it. When the button is pressed, an event is triggered to test if what the user typed in the textfield is equal to what I'm looking for. I want to make it so that instead of having a button next to it they have to click, it triggers the event whenever they hit return/enter. I've been looking up how to do this for a while now and all I've found is stuff that doesn't work or is from like 2009-10. What should I do?

this is exactly what I have:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
      if ([UserText.text isEqualToString:@"hi"] || [UserText.text isEqualToString:@"hello"]) {
          test.hidden = false;
      }
      return NO;
  }
```

I also just added

```
UserText.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Update your question with your relevant code and explain how you have things setup and explain the exact issue you are having. Otherwise everyone has to guess what you have or haven't done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    // You can trigger your events here.

      return NO;
      }
```

and also set delegate in storyboard. Whenever the user clicks on enter/return, this method will get called. You can trigger your event accordingly.

Comment: I'm using exactly what this says and it's not working. This is what I've found on like all other posts.

Comment: are you setting up delegate in storyboard?

Comment: UserText.delegate = self; put this code in viewdidload and run it..let me know if you got any issues.

Comment: i typed usertext.delegate = self; in the viewdidload and i got this

Assigning to 'id<UITextFieldDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const __strong'

Comment: i got:

Assigning to 'id<UITextFieldDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const __strong'

Comment: you made this change in .h file @interface add this UITextFieldDelegate.

Comment: .like this @interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> and run it and let me know.

Comment: ok I did that and the error disappeared but now when I run the program and I type 'hi' or 'hello' nothing happens whether I hit enter/return or i click the button

Comment: what is test here? test.hidden = false;

Comment: it's just a label that says hello on the screen. hence the name test because when i can figure out how to make this work, i'll be using it to make the game im planning to make

Comment: wait i resolved the issue. the uitextfield got unseleted in the storyboard. thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`textFieldShouldReturn:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldReturn:)?

> **Discussion**
>
> The text field calls this method whenever the user taps the return button. You can use this method to implement any custom behavior when the button is tapped.

Just make sure you set the text field's `delegate`.

Comment: Yes I'm using that and I just typed UserText.delegate = self; in the viewdidload. Read the comments of the other answer to see the errors im getting

Comment: Did you put a break point in `textFieldShouldReturn:` to make sure it is getting called?  Did you make sure `UserText` isn't nil when you set the delegate?